# I am working on AWS_SECRET but unable to put_secrets (Key/Value) pair

Tags: boto3, aws-secrets-manager

My requirement is to put_secrets in AWS_SECRET which is created by terraform and now i want to add key/value pair to my secret.
I am using python (Boto3) script to put and get values,however, if i hardcode my value like below
'{\n"username":"bob",\n"password":"abc123xyz456"\n}' it is accepting properly and also i can see Key value is being created.

I am checking if 'text_secret_data' is empty then only user should allow to put_secret (Key/value) pair.I want to do this using python without going to console.In a nutshell, i am looking for solution in which user should have right to add their own secrets in Key value format as input.

```
#Code

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import json

def get_secret():
    secret_name = "testing-secret-123"
    region_name = "eu-west-1"

    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name,
    )

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
        #print("try block")
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            print("The requested secret " + secret_name + " was not found")        
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            print("The request was invalid due to:", e)
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            print("The request had invalid params:", e)
        
    else:
        
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            text_secret_data = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
            #print(text_secret_data)
            if (tuple(json.loads(text_secret_data))) == ("",):
                print("empty string")
                response = client.put_secret_value(
                    SecretId=secret_name,                
                    
              
 SecretString='{\n"username":"bob",\n"password":"abc123xyz456"\n}'               
                    )
                #for i in range(0,3):
                #    key = input("Enter key as key")
                #    value = input("Enter Value of value")
                 #   SecretString[key]=value
                #print(SecretString)
                
            else:
                print("Key Value pair exists")        
                print(text_secret_data)   
                
        else:
            binary_secret_data = get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_secret()
```

Comment: Do you have any code demonstrating what you are trying to do?

Comment: Can anyone help me on this ?